# My code can't read properly from a file. What could be wrong?

Tags: python, class, while-loop

I am writing the code for a betting app (some fun personal project).
Part of my code asks every new user to create a username (their email) and a password, which it saves to a text file I created.

When a user wants to log in, it prompts them to enter their email. It loops through each line in the text file to see if the entered email is there. **If it is there, it gets the line, split it, and stores the affiliated password in a variable. It then prompts the user to enter the password which it compares with the one stored in a variable. If they are the same, it acknowledges that they are logged in. If the passwords are inconsistent, the   `While loop` continues.**

If the email addresses entered in is not in the text file, it tells them `Email address not linked to any account`

My problem, I think, lies in the area I highlighted above. Despite providing the necessary password, it keeps telling me `Email address not linked to any account`

What could be wrong with my code? I have included snapshots of areas which I feel are necessary in solving this question.

```py
     def login(self):
        
        self.line_holder = ''
        self.username = input("\nEnter your email: ")
        with open(r"C:\Users\"whatever.txt", 'r') as f:
            for lines in f:
                if self.username in lines:
                    self.line_holder = lines
                    break
            if self.line_holder != '':
                self.line_holder = self.line_holder.split(sep='|')
                self.expected_password = self.line_holder[2]
                self.enter_password = input(f"\nWelcome {self.line_holder[0]:25>}\nPlease enter your password: ")
                while self.enter_password != self.expected_password:
                    self.enter_password = input(f"\nThis password does not match this account.\n\tEnter your password: ")
                    if self.enter_password == self.expected_password:
                        print(f"{self.line_holder[0]} you are successfully logged in.")
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f"\n{self.line_holder[0]} you are successfully logged in.")
                    break
                    
            else:
                print("\nThis email address is not linked to any account.")
`
```

Comment: Have you inspect the file if the email and password exist?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You seem to be using `for lines in f` instead of `for lines in f.readlines()`, could this be the probelm?

Comment: @Allie no, you can iterate over each line of a file without having to read the whole lot into memory in one go, which is what `readlines` does.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea yes they exist in the specified file.

Comment: @GabrielOnyedikaNnamoko what about self.line_holder[2]? Why you used 2 instead of 1? After the split will there be more than 2 elements?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea This is how the user's login details is saved in the text file: fullname|email|password. So, yeah, I used self.line_holder[2]

Comment: What is fullname?  Is it the name spelled out, i.e. John Smith?  If so, then where is the username?

Comment: I just tried the code and it works fine. It throws errors but it gets past the if/else condition you are complaining about fine. There must be a problem with how you are storing the passwords or the filename or something, but this code works. Please update the question.

Comment: @GabrielOnyedikaNnamoko it's seems to be working on my side. The only modification I did was by remove self and :25>

Comment: Your `while` loop will only run once, because you unconditionally `break` no matter what the condition.

Comment: @JohnGordon Username is the email address.

Comment: The file must not have contained any matching lines.  As a debugging step, try printing `self.username` and also print each line as you read it.